# How to change boot menu of Debian Installer

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I want the boot menu to display just the *Automated install* option. I am planning to use the netboot, which I can build from debian-installer checkout by running `make build_netboot` (from within `build` subdirectory).

Answer (score 0):

I once needed to alter the boot menu on a debian iso. Note: this was on an older version, and it was not netboot. I hope the points below will be useful, but you may need to adapt them. In particular, check if the path of `isolinux/menu.cfg` is correct for your case.

The shell script that I used to do this worked by mounting the iso, making some changes, and then closing it up. After mounting the iso, the script contained the line:

`sed -i "s/include live.cfg/#include live.cfg/" isolinux/menu.cfg`

This removed live.cfg from the menu, so the install option appeared at the top.

My shell script contained another line you might find useful:

`sed -i "s/timeout 0/timeout 1/" isolinux/isolinux.cfg`

The idea was to force the menu to timeout after 0.1s